# How to pass a vector of a Child class in to a function expecting a vector of Parent class?

Tags: c++, vector, parent-child

I can pass in a Child to a member function expecting a Parent, however when using vectors I get a compile error saying there's no matching declaration. See the CorrelationEngineManager.cpp call to getUniqueLabels() at the bottom

ServerEvent.h

```
#ifndef SERVEREVENT_H
#define SERVEREVENT_H

#define SERVEREVENT_COLS 3

#include "Event.h"
#include <vector>


class ServerEvent: public Event {
private:

public: 
    ServerEvent(std::vector<std::string> tokens);
    void print();
};

#endif
```

Event.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include <string>

#define EVENT_STOP 0
#define EVENT_START 1

class Event {
private:

protected:
    double time;
    std::string label;
    int type; // EVENT_START OR EVENT_STOP

public:

};

#endif
```

CorrelationEngineManager.h

```
class CorrelationEngineManager {
private:
    std::vector<ServerEvent> s_events;
    std::vector<UPSEvent> u_events;
    std::vector<TimeRecord> s_timeRecords;
    std::vector<TimeRecord> u_timeRecords;
    // typeOfEvent gets type of event, 0 for error, look at #defines for codes
    int typeOfEvent(std::vector<std::string>);
    int createTimeRecords();
    std::vector<std::string> getUniqueLabels(std::vector<Event> events);


public:
    CorrelationEngineManager();
    //~CorrelationEngineManager();
    int addEvent(std::vector<std::string> tokens); //add event given tokens
    void print_events();
};
```

CorrelationEngineManager.cpp

```
int CorrelationEngineManager::createTimeRecords() {
    std::vector<std::string> u_sLabels; // unique server labels
    std::vector<std::string> u_uLabels; // unique UPS labels
    u_sLabels = getUniqueLabels(s_events);
//  u_uLabels = getUniqueLabels(u_events);
    return 1;
}
// returns a vector of unique labels, input a vector of events
std::vector<std::string> CorrelationEngineManager::getUniqueLabels(std::vector<Event> events) {

    std::vector<std::string> temp;
    return temp;
}
```

compile error

```
 CorrelationEngineManager.cpp: In member function ‘int CorrelationEngineManager::createTimeRecords()’:
 CorrelationEngineManager.cpp:60: error: no matching function for call
 to ‘CorrelationEngineManager::getUniqueLabels(std::vector<ServerEvent,
 std::allocator<ServerEvent> >&)’ CorrelationEngineManager.h:23: note:
 candidates are: std::vector<std::basic_string<char,
 std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
 std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
 std::allocator<char> > > >
 CorrelationEngineManager::getUniqueLabels(std::vector<Event,
 std::allocator<Event> >) make: *** [CorrelationEngineManager.o] Error 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How do I pass a container of derived classes to a function expecting a container of their base classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376334/c-how-do-i-pass-a-container-of-derived-classes-to-a-function-expecting-a-cont)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in C++, this requires a feature called **covariance**.

Even if type `A` is a subclass of type `B`, **type `X<A>` is completely unrelated to type `X<B>`**

Thus you cannot pass `std::vector<UPSEvent>` to a function expecting `std::vector<Event>`, since **they are unrelated types**. Even pass by reference/pointer will not work.

There are two ways to get around this.

One would be to make both vectors **hold pointers to `Event`**, then they would have identical types.

The other, would be to make the function a **template function**, as Daniel suggests.

You would need to **fix the signature** as well, as billz points out.

Answer (score 3):

The function could be changed to a template function:

```
template< typename T >
std::vector<std::string> getUniqueLabels(std::vector<T> events);
```

Comment: if I have to call a events member function (common to the parent and child class) how can I do that?

Comment: @Rorschach I'm not sure I understand the question. You'd just call it, e.g., `for(const auto & e : events) e.some_func();`.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear. Basically with templates you created a template function that accepts as parameter a vector of parent class or a vector of the child class. Suppose I want to call a member function of one element of the vector, for example events.at(idx).any_function(), being any_function() a function both of the parent class and inherited by the child class. Hope to have been a little more clear

Comment: @Rorschach I still don't see the problem. If you have a child class derived from a parent class and that parent class has a member function, you can just call the member function on an instance of the child class. If this doesn't work, something else might be wrong. Please create a minimal but complete example to expose your problem and ask a new question about it as it seems to be too complex to handle it in some comments.